# Prestashop Stripe is not defined

Tags: stripe-payments, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules, stripe-payments-js

I try to implement Stripe module in my Prestashop project.

After installation and configuration in the back-office, I dont get the Stripe form in my order page.

However I get a JS error like:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (checkout.js:18:48061)
```

I checked the page of module **stripe_official.php** And everthing is OK the **js.stripe.com** is called and I see it in the code source of the order page.

```
    $this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
        $this->name . '-stripe-v3',
        'https://js.stripe.com/v3/',
        [
            'server' => 'remote',
            'position' => 'head',
        ]
    );
    $this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
        $this->name . '-payments',
        'modules/' . $this->name . '/views/js/checkout.js'
    );

    if (Configuration::get(self::ENABLE_APPLEPAY_GOOGLEPAY)) {
        $this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
            $this->name . '-stripepaymentrequest',
            'modules/' . $this->name . '/views/js/payment_request.js'
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've installed and configured correctly as mentioned in the docs?
https://stripe.com/docs/connectors/prestashop

If so, I would suggest you reach out to Stripe support about that and see if they can help provide more context on why you're seeing this error.
https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true

Answer (score 0):

I just download the official version of Stripe module from the Marketplace (https://addons.prestashop.com/en/payment-card-wallet/24922-stripe-official-sca-ready.html) and install it locally and also on the test env and it's working fine, without errors.

I would recommend you uninstall the module by marking the checkbox ( Optional: delete module folder after uninstall.) and after that to clear the cache from Prestashop back-office: Advanced Parameters -> Performance and then install the module again.